# Html - float: left on logo results in text after logo moving up?

Tags: css

Im learning html and css for now. Anyway, I am following a course, and have a queston.

This is my example code with logo of BBC and text next to it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5kFn.png

And once I add float: left; to logo, text moves up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jx5s.png

Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

This is because by default your browser is rendering the image and the text as inline elements, therefore the baseline, or bottom of the image and text is lining up.

When you apply float:left to the image, it forces the image to display as a block rather than inline, so the text no long aligns baselines with it.

Answer (score 1):

you can control them using different divs. `<div class="wrapper"> <div>logo</div> <div>text</div> <div>` you can control them separate, but try using float:left on the text as well, that might help.

Comment: Yea, I get that . I was just wondering why it works like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, an `img` in html by default will take up the entire line that it's height occupies.

When you give an element the property of 'float', you tell it to become part of the regular flow of the page, and other elements can now wrap around it.

You may want to read up on both the [float property](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) and the [inline-block](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp)